# How to create an auto updating Adaptive Tile in Windows 10 using C#

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, live-tile

I would like to create an Auto Updating Adaptive live tile in windows 10.  I have a webservice i need to call to get the status of a few things and return and i would like to be able to publish that to the tile,  if the user clicks the tile it opens a hyperlink (to a SAAS Solution)

I have spent some time googling and i have spent some time going through MSDN and i've found all the stuff on tile notifications and the XML to produce the actual tile,  i know it needs to go into a UWP project,  however i cannot for the life of me figure out where in that project it needs to go,  or what actually calls the updating etc,  i'm not creating an app that runs on the client as far as i'm aware?  i just want a live tile that i can update content on every 30 minutes from a custom web service.

Does anyone know of an example (preferably c#,  though any .NET language would probably be fine and i can backwards engineer) of how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I think what you need is **Periodic notification**.

> Periodic notifications, which are also called polled notifications, update tiles and badges at a fixed interval by downloading content from a cloud service. To use periodic notifications, your client app code needs to provide two pieces of information:
>
> - The Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) of a web location for Windows to poll for tile or badge updates for your app
> - How often that URI should be polled
>
> Periodic notifications enable your app to get live tile updates with minimal cloud service and client investment. Periodic notifications are a good delivery method for distributing the same content to a wide audience.

The UWP side is simple, you can refer to [Quickstart: Setting up periodic notifications (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868228) and [Push and periodic notifications sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=231476) for Windows 8.1 and re-using its source code in your Windows 10 app. For the server side, you need provide a URI that can accept HTTP GET request and return the correct tile content as XML.

For more info, please see [**Periodic notification overview**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-periodic-notification-overview).

Answer (score 0):

An app needs to be installed on client to have a tile space available for you. Then you can update the tile through [push notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview) or by [running a background task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-a-background-task-on-a-timer-).

Comment: I don't mind installing on the client,  i just didn't figure i would have an app running. all i want this app to do is manage this live tile.  This is the kind of info i have already found...  what i have not found is where i put this stuff into the Universal App?

Comment: @Nikerym check the links I provided.

Comment: Yes,  i get the concept,  but where in the UWapp do i add "BackgroundTaskRegistration task = RegisterBackgroundTask(entryPoint, taskName, hourlyTrigger, userCondition);"

Comment: @Nikerym Check out this [BackgroundTask Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundTask) on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

[UWP Toolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit) released by Microsoft a few days ago may help you, there is a part regarding Live tiles managing there